# PDO fetchall() performance considerations?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

After reading a few articles on the performance impact of PHP's PDO `fetchall()` function, I am curious if there is another way to accomplish the same outcome without invoking `fetchall()`.

To explain, most agree that `fetchall()` tends to be resource intensive.  In my case, I don't believe it will be too big of an issue. Yes, I am having to pull an entire table from my database and display it to the user, but it is going to be about a 100 rows at the very most; I don't believe that will be an issue. Hypothetically, though, if I were needing to pull 100,000 rows, what would be a more optimal solution?

Comment: If you need all the rows in memory at a single time i would think fetchall would be the way to go. I think it keeps the iteration/fetching on the `C` side so it should be faster than looping over the statement and filling your own array on the php side.

Comment: The solution is not to pull 100,000 rows at once. You only take the information you need at that point of time, in order to complete the work for your application. Unless you need some extensive statistical calculations, I see very very little cases where you actually need all 100k rows at a time. Hypothetically.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. The 100,000 is just a hyperbole; the point is to simply present a situation in which `fetchall()` becomes too resource intensive to be practical. At that point, what is a more optimal solution? I'm sure there are others that have needed to present a considerable amount of data to a user where performance inevitably becomes a consideration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hypothetically, if you need to output all 100,000 rows in a single response, you should set `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` to `false`, execute the query, and iterate the resultset one row at a time using [fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). To elaborate, php buffers the entire resultset regardless of whether or not you call fetchAll() if `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` is set to true.

The benefit is that you drastically reduce the max memory consumption of the script, and you get to start streaming output sooner, although total time to completion may or may not take longer.

I'm ignoring other things you should consider in such extreme circumstances, like output buffering etc...

Answer (score 2):

Alternative is to fetch one row after another inside a loop, like this:

```
while( $row = $statement->fetch() ){
    // so something with $row
}
```

Obviously, if you need all rows e.g. to calculate some statistics with them, then the above does not work. In many cases, though, SQL provides solutions that allow you to calculate such statistics on the fly, and return just the result.