# Speeding Up PDO Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following PHP code:

```
public function indexload(){

        $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
        $pdo->setAttribute($pdo::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);

        $count = $pdo->query('select count(id) from clans')->fetchColumn();

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SET @rownum = 0');
        $stmt->execute();

        $selectSql = 'SELECT @rownum := @rownum+1 AS rank, id, clanid, name, location, level, exp, warslost, warstied, warwinpercent, warswon, playercount, score
                      FROM clans
                      ORDER BY clanid ASC';
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($selectSql);
        $statement->execute();

        $clan = $statement->fetchAll();

        return  [
            'draw' => 1,
            'recordsTotal' => $count,
            'recordsFiltered' => count($clan),
            'data' => $clan,
        ];
    }
```

I am using it to generate a DataTables table.

The above code outputs: http://clashdata.tk/clans/load but as you can see it is taking a very long time. Is there a way for me to make my code quicker?

Comment: have you tried the explaining the query (in your db manager)

Comment: using non-buffered queries will have a negative impact on performance, among other things.  It's not advisable to use unless you have an extremely large return set. ie > 100k rows.  Also in combination with fetchAll sort of defeats the purpose, not to mention fetchAll is a non-preferred way of returning results because of its memory usage.  On top of that your creating a variable `@rownum` and never using it or returning it.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix It is returning 157+K rows, hence non-buffered. What is the preferred way then? I am using the variable `@rownum `...

Comment: See - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221861/pdo-fetchall-performance-considerations

Comment: Explain won't help here.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I am using `@rownum`...

Comment: @ShivamPaw - I don't see where `rank` is used. `@rownum := @rownum+1 AS rank`  You may be incrementing it but...

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix it is used when I display the table...

Comment: @ShivamPaw - ok, i see where it is returned now.  I would think that the main issue is that if you have 157k rows displaying that is a lot of data to send over the network ( from the database and to the client browser ), run the query without the output and see.  Best all around suggestion is do some kind of search / paging.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I use DataTables to do the pagination client side because I need to be able to filter through all results with DataTables search. I will do that test now though.

Comment: @ShivamPaw - also in regards to non buffered queries, once you store all the data in memory it defeats the whole purpose of doing it, the idea here is to stream the data, such as read 1 row output it, dump memory ( handled by php ) .. rinse repeat.  Thereby avoiding a large memory overhead at the experience of immediate performance.  An example would be writing a CSV file, you would read one line, format it, output it to the file, repeat.  Then the memory usage is limited to only that row, where a buffered query would load the whole result set upfront.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95482/discussion-between-shivam-paw-and-artisiticphoenix). @ArtisiticPhoenix

Comment: Non buffered makes more network calls, ( to get each row at a time ) hence the "immediate" performance hit.  But with a large dataset, you could run the risk of not having enough memory in PHP to hold the whole dataset "upfront" when using buffered queries.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix check our chat.

Comment: I think it's always easier to filter rows using WHERE and limit them with LIMIT statement. That's what database is made for and it will always be faster than fetching all and looping through results